# react native web view is not rendering content

Tags: html, react-native, webview

I have an old app in react-native with some webview components that are not rendering their provided html content.

The react native version is "react-native": "^0.53.0"

We noticed the problem from android version 8 on, older android versions are working ok.

I have found that the problem is resolved if we change the inline css color codes for example from **#efefef** to **rgb(239, 239, 239)**

Is there a global way to solve the rendering without changing the html source? Because I have multiple web views rendering different html and it would not be elegant to change every html.

I also don't have the option to upgrade the app to something newer as there are to many old components and unfortunately we do not have time to do a major rewrite.

Comment: I have changed all related html content to have the rgb for now, if someone find a better solution I would be glad to hear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a recent change in the M72 Android WebView release. You're now required to properly encode content passed into `WebView.loadData()` (the change in question was to treat "#" differently).

As a React Native app, your best workaround would be to change all content as you've suggested (although, you need to avoid/encode **all** "#" symbols, not just for colors). A proper fix would need to come from React Native itself (to properly encode your content).

More details here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=929083